# Problems when running project with two main mehods in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

[image]In my project I have two different classes with main methods to create different objects of different classes. But when I want to run one of the classes with a main method, it starts and run the other object that is created in the other main method!?

Perhaps a little bit confusing, but I hope the reader can understand what I'm trying to explain. I have googled and found some info about do some changes in the properties for the classes, but I couldn't find out how. Preciate some help! Thanks!

EDIT:
Perhaps I was unclear. I have main class called TaxProgram and it contain the main method that creats an object of the class Product.

Then I have another class called StartBox and it also contain a main method but it creates an object of the class Box.

The problem is when I press F5 to Debug, I thought that the merked tab with the class name StartBox should start and create an object of the box class, but now I knew that VisualStudio doesn't work that way. I have tried to change the properties to be able to start the StartBox insetad, but without any luck.

The image gives a view of my classes

Comment: Some of your existing code might help, since it's unclear what you mean by 'two main methods'.  Do you mean you have two methods with the same name and you're overloading them, but the overload doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Would you please explain how you 'run a class'? Classes can't be 'run'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open project properties  + Application Tab + set Startup object.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a standard Main signature :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Then, you should only have *one* function like this in your program. Rename the other one.

IIRC there is an option in the project properties to set which class's Main is called at startup, but I can't confirm this until I get to work.

Answer (score 0):

Click with the right button in your solution, then select "Set StartUp Projects..."

Answer (score 0):

In the project properties, in the Application tab, is an option for Startup object. You can select the class that contains your intended entry point, as long as it contains a valid Main method.

Comment: I found it, but I get an error message saying: "The debug mode is program, but there is no program specified...." It' seems like I can only select project names, not the files!?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Go to the Debug tab and select Start project, instead of Start external program.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I get this error all the time! I right click on Solution... ans then properties and then Single startup project

Comment: Not the solution properties, the project properties. This has nothing to do with the solution.

Comment: Sorry! But I get the same error dispite that I try to change in the Project dropdown menu and Set as start up project. If I don't do the last thing I cant select it in the start up tab inside the projects properties, bu as I wrote same error message! :(

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that I created a new project at the Solution explorer instead of File -> New project!?

Comment: You didn't follow my instructions, did you? I never said anything about Startup Projects. RTFA

Comment: Hmm, could you be kind and tell me where to find the right place?

Comment: Like I said in the answer, Project properties > Application tab > Startup object

Comment: See my comment on the question. Maybe I can help you more with more detail.

Comment: With run I mean to press F5 then the class with the static void Main(string[] args) method start and create an object of another class

Comment: I'm sorry, you need to explain your whole situation in a lot more detail, or I won't be able to help.

Comment: I added an image from my solution visual studio that might help?